# Text embeddings for words or very short sentences with a LLM

Tags: word-embeddings

I tried to compute the semantic similarity between words or short sentences.
Ex : inflation vs price raising

I have tried the openai embeddings API and cosine distance but the results are very poor.

I would prefer not to train a model on my own data but to rely on a pretrained LLM.

Any alternative to openai embeddings API ?
Thanks a lot